# ahref to other website including php variable html in a table

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a website that with html creates a table and populate the table using php and data from a sql database. It all works just fine but I wish to create a link to another website of each of my entries in my table. I have my php code like this

```
while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr>
     <td>".$row["name"]."</td>
```

Here I wish to add a hyperlink, so the users can click a name and being sent to another website than mine. So with every of my instance of name, will go to a website like www.facebook.com/name

I thought I could do something like
        `<td>"<a href=https//www.facebook.com/$name>".$row["name"]."</td>`

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
     echo '<tr>
     <td><a href="https://www.google.com">'.$row["name"].'</a></td>';
   }
```

If you wanted to store the URL in the database you can do this:

```
  while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
         echo '<tr>
         <td><a href="'. $row["url"] .'">'.$row["name"].'</a></td>';
       }
```

For your particular question, you need to do this:

```
 while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
         echo '<tr>
         <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com"'.$row["name"].'">'.$row["name"].'</a></td>';
       }
```

Comment: Just to be super annoying, you could wrap the string in single quotes and avoid escaping the double quote ( \") as the variable is concatenated with the '.$var.' syntax. Just makes it a bit less error prone.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just what I needed to go further. Cheers! @Julian

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Updated to reflect your point, I didn't think about that

Comment: @PeterHoldensgaard Check the edited answer, like TimBrownlaw said, using single quotes and not escaping double quotes makes the code less error prone